# Cannot get elements from Vector from other class (Thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, list, vector

i have this Class (my Server start Class), here i create with every new Client a new Thread for him. After the Thread was createt, i add him to the Vector (list) to keep Track of active users and connections, so that i can send messages to a specific user. But i cant Access the Vector-List from my Thread (its the class below). Can you explain me, how i can do this? I have a private list and public setter and getter methods but i always get the size 1 from the Vector. But i testet it, if i connect with more then one client there are multiple Threads with different socket creates. I can add Entrys to the vector if i do it manuel in my server start class.

```
package securemessageserver;

public class SecureMessageServer {

private Vector<SecureMessageServerClientThread> userList = new Vector();
private SSLServerSocket sslserversocket;
int port = 9999;
private Boolean isRunning=true;
SSLSocket sslsocket;

private synchronized void loadCertificat(){
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/securemessageserver/keystore.jks");
        File file = new File(url.toURI());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/keystore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "Schelkan1994");
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
        System.out.println("Certifikat geladen");
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);;
        stopServer();
    }
}

private synchronized void createSocket(){
    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();    
        sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Socket erstellt mit "+port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        stopServer();
    }
}

private synchronized void startServer(SSLServerSocket sslserversocket){
    while(isRunning){
        try {
            System.out.println("Akzeptiere Verbindungen");
            sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
            SecureMessageServerClientThread client = new SecureMessageServerClientThread(sslsocket);
            startNewClient(client);
            userList.add(client);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            stopServer();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void startNewClient(SecureMessageServerClientThread th){
    new Thread(th).start();
}

public synchronized void stopServer(){
    isRunning=false;
}

public synchronized SSLServerSocket getServerSocket(){
    if(sslserversocket!=null){
        return this.sslserversocket;
    }
    return null;
}

public synchronized void addThreadToList(SecureMessageServerClientThread thread){
    userList.add(thread);
}

public synchronized void getAllThreadFromList(){
        System.out.println("Size: "+userList.size());
}

public synchronized String getUserName(){
    return userList.get(0).getUserOfThread();
}

public synchronized void deleteThreadFromList(SecureMessageServerClientThread thread){
    userList.remove(thread);
}

public synchronized void getUserNameOfAllThreads(){
    for(int i=0;userList.size()>i;i++){
        System.out.println(userList.get(i).getUserOfThread());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     SecureMessageServer server = new SecureMessageServer();
     server.loadCertificat();
     server.createSocket();
     server.startServer(server.sslserversocket);
}
```

}

And hier ist the other class (My Thread Class) instanze of this class if always createt if new client connect to keep track of the connection and to perform input and output operations. But i dont get the right value from the Vector in the other class ... Do you see my error? Thanks for help

```
public class SecureMessageServerClientThread implements Runnable{

private SSLSocket socket;
private String userName;
boolean isRunning=true;

SecureMessageServer server = new SecureMessageServer();

public SecureMessageServerClientThread(SSLSocket socket){
    this.socket=socket;
}

private ObjectInputStream sInput;
private ObjectOutputStream sOutput;

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Client mit Socket is Running: "+socket);
    while(isRunning){
    try {
        sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        SecureMessageServerClientMessage msg = (SecureMessageServerClientMessage) sInput.readObject();
        if(msg.getType()==0){
            System.out.println("All Threads:");
            server.getAllThreadFromList();
        }else if(msg.getType()==1){
            System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
        }else if(msg.getType()==2){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            socket.close();
            this.stopThread();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Unbekannter Nachrichtentyp");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServerClientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServerClientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecureMessageServerClientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public void stopThread(){
    isRunning=false;


 //                 sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}

public String getUserOfThread(){
    return this.userName;
}

public void getUserList(){
    server.getAllThreadFromList();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SecureMessageServerClientThread`, you create a new Server instance with `SecureMessageServer server = new SecureMessageServer();`.

This means that when you call `server.getAllThreadFromList()` in `getUserList`, you're getting the list from the server you just created which has no clients.

The Client thread should instead take the server instance as a parameter:

```
SecureMessageServer server;

public SecureMessageServerClientThread(SSLSocket socket, SecureMessageServer server){
    this.socket=socket;
    this.server=server;
}
```

And in the Server, you should pass `this` to the new client instance:

```
SecureMessageServerClientThread client = new SecureMessageServerClientThread(sslsocket, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is private you obviously can't access from another class. Make it protected and make both classes be in same package.

Comment: They are in the same Package and why is privat not ok if i have public setter and getter?